# How to draw lines on top of triangle?

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, z-index

Is there a way to draw a `gl.LINE_LOOP` always on top of `gl.TRIANGLES` while still using same program and points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but `gl.LINE_LOOP` will always connect the first and last points which is probably not what you want.

In any case the default depth function is `gl.LESS` meaning with depth testing on WebGL will only render pixels if their depth value is less than that pixel's current depth value. So, change it to `gl.LEQUAL` and you should get what you want.

```
gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);
```

```js
"use strict";
twgl.setDefaults({attribPrefix: "a_"});
const v3 = twgl.v3;
const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = twgl.getWebGLContext(document.getElementById("c"));

// compiles shaders, links program, looks up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ["vs", "fs"]);

// calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData 
const bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createSphereBufferInfo(gl, 1, 16, 8);

var uniforms = {
  u_lightDir: twgl.v3.normalize([1, 20, -10]),
};

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);
  
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  const fov = 30 * Math.PI / 180;
  const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  const zNear = 0.5;
  const zFar = 10;
  var projection = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
  var eye = [1, 3, -5];
  var target = [0, 0, 0];
  var up = [0, 1, 0];

  var camera = m4.lookAt(eye, target, up);
  var view = m4.inverse(camera);
  var viewProjection = m4.multiply(projection, view);
  var world = m4.rotationY(time);

  uniforms.u_worldInverseTranspose = m4.transpose(m4.inverse(world));
  uniforms.u_worldViewProjection = m4.multiply(viewProjection, world);

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  
  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);

  // calls gl.uniform
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    u_ambient: [0, 0, 0],
    u_diffuse: [1, 0, 0],
  });
  
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, bufferInfo.numElements, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

  // calls gl.uniform
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    u_ambient: [1, 1, 0],
    u_diffuse: [0, 0, 0],
  });

  gl.drawElements(gl.LINE_LOOP, bufferInfo.numElements, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { display: block; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script id="vs" type="notjs">
uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection;
uniform mat4 u_world;
uniform mat4 u_worldInverseTranspose;

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec3 a_normal;

varying vec3 v_normal;

void main() {
  v_normal = (u_worldInverseTranspose * vec4(a_normal, 0)).xyz;
  gl_Position = u_worldViewProjection * a_position;
}
</script>
<script id="fs" type="notjs">
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 v_normal;

uniform vec3 u_lightDir;
uniform vec3 u_diffuse;
uniform vec3 u_ambient;

void main() {
  vec3 a_normal = normalize(v_normal);
  float light = dot(a_normal, u_lightDir) * .5 + .5;
  gl_FragColor = vec4(u_diffuse * light + u_ambient, 1);
}
</script>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
```